# stop audio after 10 sec in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to stop the audio after 30 sec in html audio player and sign in model should pop up after signing in same page should appear can anyone help me.

```
<audio id="aud" controls autoplay>
  <source src="infinity%20love/01%20Infinite%20Love%20(English)-(Pagalworld.Com).mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>




<script type="text/javascript">
    var myaud = document.getElementById("aud");
    var k = setInterval("pauseAud()", 10000);

    function playAud() {
        myaud.play();
    }

    function pauseAud() {
        myaud.pause();
        alert('Audio Stop Successfully');
        clearInterval(k);
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: try `setTimeout(pauseAud,30000)`. Also `setInterval` takes function and not string.

Comment: why do you answer by comment instead of adding answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var k = setInterval("pauseAud", 10000);
```

not  setInterval("pauseAud()", 10000);

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var k = setInterval(pauseAud,30000);
```

As Ramesh has already mentioned in the comments,setInterval takes a function as an argument and not a string.